# How can I learn VMP analysis？

Tags: ida, vmprotect

I am currently interested in learning reverse engineering, and I have a

- foundation in assembly,
- PE structure,
- and the use of Win32Api.
- And also have some of the foundation for writing Windows drivers;

I Can use IDA to analyze assembly code without confusion.

How can I learn [VMProtect](https://github.com/JonathanSalwan/VMProtect-devirtualization) restoration analysis?